# Docker Build Ending Up `returned a non-zero code: 1`

Tags: docker, containers

```
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
        This may take some time... done.
build.sh: line 81: -: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c bash build.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

You can view the code here.

https://github.com/austinsonger/GreenOpenVAS

Answer (score 1):

[Line 81 of build.sh](https://github.com/austinsonger/vulnscout/blob/main/build.sh#L81) is trying to run python3.  But the problem is more fundamental because you aren't getting any of the earlier `echo`s or `apt-get` command's output.  I would try:

```
chmod +x build.sh
./build.sh
```

to let the sh-bang line do its job.